# Erro ao tentar preencher um listview

Tags: android, listview

Estou tentando preencher meu listview assim

```
historicos=banco.getAllH(); 
ArrayAdapter<HistoricoObjeto> itens = new ArrayAdapter<HistoricoObjeto>(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, historicos); 

this.lista.setAdapter(itens);
this.lista.setClickable(true);
registerForContextMenu(lista);
```

Mais está dando erro de null pointer exception  nesta linha

```
this.lista.setAdapter(itens);
```

Vou colocar a classe HistoticoObjeto para ficar mais claro oque e o objeto que eu uso

```
public class HistoricoObjeto implements Serializable{

    private String id;
    public String datahora;
    public String mensagem;

    public HistoricoObjeto() {

    }

    public HistoricoObjeto(String id, String datahora, String mensagem) {
        super();
        this.setId(id);
        this.setDatahora(datahora);
        this.setMensagem(mensagem); 
    }
}
```

Alguém sabe me dizer aonde estou errando?

```
11-25 12:22:02.809: E/AndroidRuntime(11457): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-25 12:22:02.809: E/AndroidRuntime(11457): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.ilgner.chegouahora/com.ilgner.chegouahora.Historico}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-25 12:22:02.809: E/AndroidRuntime(11457):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2124)
11-25 12:22:02.809: E/AndroidRuntime(11457):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
11-25 12:22:02.809: E/AndroidRuntime(11457):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1672)
11-25 12:22:02.809: E/AndroidRuntime(11457):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-25 12:22:02.809: E/AndroidRuntime(11457):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
11-25 12:22:02.809: E/AndroidRuntime(11457):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-25 12:22:02.809: E/AndroidRuntime(11457):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-25 12:22:02.809: E/AndroidRuntime(11457):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
11-25 12:22:02.809: E/AndroidRuntime(11457):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 12:22:02.809: E/AndroidRuntime(11457):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-25 12:22:02.809: E/AndroidRuntime(11457):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
11-25 12:22:02.809: E/AndroidRuntime(11457):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
11-25 12:22:02.809: E/AndroidRuntime(11457):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-25 12:22:02.809: E/AndroidRuntime(11457): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-25 12:22:02.809: E/AndroidRuntime(11457):    at com.ilgner.chegouahora.Historico.onResume(Historico.java:62)
11-25 12:22:02.809: E/AndroidRuntime(11457):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1150)
11-25 12:22:02.809: E/AndroidRuntime(11457):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3832)
11-25 12:22:02.809: E/AndroidRuntime(11457):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
11-25 12:22:02.809: E/AndroidRuntime(11457):    ... 12 more




    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_historico);
    this.lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvContatos);
    this.banco = new Banco(getApplicationContext());
    HistoricoObjeto historico = new HistoricoObjeto();
    brCollator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    historicos=banco.getAllH();

    historicos=ordena(brCollator, historicos);
    ArrayAdapter<HistoricoObjeto> itens = new ArrayAdapter<HistoricoObjeto>(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, historicos){ 
        @Override
        public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                // Como o simple_list_item_1 retorna um TextView, esse cast pode ser feito sem problemas
                ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                return view;
            }}; 

    Log.e("", ""+itens.getCount());
    this.lista.setAdapter(itens);
    this.lista.setClickable(true);
    registerForContextMenu(lista);

}
```

Estranho parou de da este erro ai , e eu nem fiz nada , mais eu usei este codigo ai em outra lista mais ão era com o Historico era com uma classe Pessoa que tinha nome , e telefone ai na lista aparecia o nome , mais agora não to sabendo como fazer aparecer uma das variáveis na lista a classe histórico tem data e hora e mensagem queria fazer aparecer as duas ou uma

Comment: Você não está por acaso esquecendo de fazer `this.lista = findViewById(...);`?

Comment: faço isso no oncreate 
this.lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvContatos);

Comment: Poste todo o log de erro para termos mais informação.

Comment: coloquei na pergunta o log

Comment: É necessário termos acesso a mais do seu código, principalmente `onCreate` e `onResume`. Você tem a certeza que `this.lista` não é `null`?

Comment: Olha la no on create eu faço o finfviewbyid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`historicos=banco.getAllH();` esse comando ele retorna uma lista ou um vetor?

Porque se for vetor, está coerente, pois o último parâmetro do construtor do ArrayAdapter deve ser um vetor;

Erros do tipo NullPointException é ocorre quando o programa tenta acessar um objeto de memória que não foi instanciado (ou melhor, inicializado) até o momento de sua chamada. O que isso quer dizer? O **historicos** ainda está nulo ou ele não tem um valor definido.

Sugiro que use Log, para saber se há algum valor dentro de **historicos**.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Ele retorna um ArrayList<HistoricoObjeto>

Comment: analise as seguintes suspeitas:

Comment: * veja se você está adicionando corretamente no banco, para que o retorno dele seja diferente de Null. Uma outra forma de você saber se tem algo no banco é dando um database.getSize(), que ele retornará o tamanho.
* você está adicionando em um ArrayAdapter um array de objetos; você realmente precisa de todas as informações dentro desse objeto ou de algum específico? Tipo... você precisa só da mensagem, ou da mensagem, datahora e id?
Porque se você precisar só da mensagem, crie um outro array do tipo string e atribua esses valores!

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, muito obrigado a todos

Comment: Resolvi meu problema coloca um toString

Comment: @Ilgner publique a solução que você encontrou e marque-a como resposta aceita. Fazendo assim ficará claro que você já encontrou uma solução.